# Angular google-maps and AdvancedMarkerElement

Tags: angular, google-maps-markers, angular-google-maps

I would like to use AdvancedMarkerElemment in my component using @angular/google-maps

Since AdvancedMarkerElement is not yet supported by @angular/google-maps I need your help to include and use an [AdvancedMarkerElement](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/advanced-markers) in my component.

Any help of how to do it appreciated.
Regards

Armando

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

It's now included in version `17.3.0-next.0`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/google-maps/v/17.3.0-next.0

Hope this helps.